# Click on screen, open Layout where it was clicked

Tags: android, api, google-maps, kotlin, tooltip

I'm want to create something like this :

I have a google maps screen. When I click on the map, it opens my custom "tooltip" where the screen was clicked (my data in my custom tooltip).

Is that technically possible? I don't want to start something impossible ^^

Comment: what you have tried so far? where is your code?

Comment: yes it is possible - your "tooltips" are called [markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker)

Comment: @NoumanCh not yet, I wanted to be sure that is possible (in fact, I've created my custom maker (as pskink said), but that all). And I think that I'm will start again because I use some Relative Layout to make marker. Maybe there's easiest way. Thanks !

Comment: Yes. It's possible.